# I can't access to Nifi Ui

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apache-nifi

I have installed docker on Ubuntu-21.04 and I'm trying to run apache/nifi on it. I am using this command: `docker run --name nifi -dp 8443:8443 apache/nifi`. From the logs all seems fine:

```
Generated Username [24a06eea-579f-443a-ad81-b9fe95d46bd3]
Generated Password [9D3NKqhLElChcXHw0jzfO/wkT8yOV+uV]

2022-03-24 15:39:27,726 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
2022-03-24 15:39:27,726 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://a8917820086b:8443/nifi
```

The entire logs are [here](https://pastebin.com/Ajj6yZJf)

But if i go at localhost:8443 I see this:
[on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQSZl.png)
[and on chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdaNx.png)
I don't know why I can't access to the UI of Nifi.
I have done all of this exactly on windows 10 and it works. Someone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please try adding nifi to the URL - Example: https://localhost:8443/nifi

Comment: [sf] would be a better fit for this sort of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to `https://localhost:8443` not `http://localhost:8443`. By default NiFi is now secured with TLS, but 8443 is not the standard HTTPS port, thus it does not automatically redirect you to HTTPS if you only enter `localhost`

Comment: @emanuelecannizzo Glad it works :) Please help others find the answer by accepting the answer that solved your problem